# page automatic submit after time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

*i want to submit paper after time interval if user not click on button.I use meta for this but this is not resolve my problem i want to set the value of auto redirect to another page as user enter but in this meta tag i am not give the variabe....
One an other issue is that if user refresh the page then time start with 0 again it is a big issue how i resolve this plz tell me early

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="autosubmitpaper.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10;url=WebForm2.aspx" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="WebForm2.aspx" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label>Give Answer</label>
   <input type="text" id="text1" />
        <label>Give Answer</label>
    <input type="text" id="text2" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">paper submit after 10 sec</asp:Label>
   <asp:button ID="button" OnClick="button_Click" runat="server" text="Button" />     
         </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*
Humbly request if any have any other method for this...please resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use an interval timer to submit the form

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#form1').submit();
}, 30000); // 30 seconds
```

Comment: Sir where i call the settimeout function

Comment: In a script tag or script file. If there are special conditions to not trigger it then you need to be more specific

Comment: Sir in script i type the code you give but this javascript code run on button click ..I want to without button click automatically runout if user not enter the button and timeout

Comment: The code I gave you has nothing to do with button click. It simply submits the form when 30 seconds has elapsed and is not dependent on anything but time

Comment: Yes sir its work....I want if during this time user refresh the page then value start time from 0 what i do for this

Comment: When you reload the page it starts all over

Comment: sir let suppose during exam student start paper and the time for paper is 10 minute and user answer one question and by mistake click on refresh then every thing distrub like time

Comment: You could use localStorage or server side session to store start time and set duration accordingly

Comment: sir please with code tell how use local storage  session to store start time because when session start then how i calculate the time

Comment: Start by doing some research...this isn't a code writing service and you are expected to do research yourself.

Comment: thanks sir for help me ..i research on it if not done then i tell u..
Thanks a lot sir

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: don't post your email address here...suggest you delete that comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build-in asp.net Control `Timer` for that. More info at the [Microsoft Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865.aspx)

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

`OnTick` performs a normal PostBack and you can do the usual things in code behind.

> The `Interval` is in milliseconds

Comment: how i give the interval value which user want for paper

Comment: and if user refresh then timer start also from start

Comment: is there any other method for this

Comment: You can access it's properties in code behind like any other Control: `Timer1.Interval = 1500;`. And yes the times starts from start.

Comment: its not correct start from start how i resolve this please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.setTimeout (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)) to execute a JavaScript function after the specified number of milliseconds. In the function you could then submit the form or just redirect to another page.

If you want the timeout to outlive a page refresh, then you would need to store some information in the user's session and use that to calculate the remaining timeout if he refreshes the page.

Comment: Sir Quagaar where i call the function

Comment: You could just add a small JavaScript block to your <head>, possibly something like this:

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
  var timeout = 1234; // Timeout in ms
  window.setTimeout(function() {
   // react to timeout
  }, timeout);
 })();
</script>`

Comment: Sir i have issue if user refresh then not time start form 0 during exam plz tell me if u know

Comment: Sir you are say using session..plz tell me  how with session i judge if refresh..please sir tell me its my final project issue and i have so much short time and i am not handle this

Comment: Store in the session the time when the user first opens the page and on subsequent calls use this information to calculate the remaining timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function () {
        var initialDate = new Date();
       var x = setInterval(function () {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var variation = (currentDate - initialDate) + parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('key') == null ? 0 : sessionStorage.getItem('key'));
            console.log(variation);
            sessionStorage.setItem('key', variation);
            if (variation > 60000) {
                alert("I am done");
                clearInterval(x);
                sessionStorage.setItem('key', 0);
            }

        }, 1000);


    });
```

Try this (end time is 6 sec, if you refresh at 3rd second it will count from 3rd to 6).

Comment: sir if i run this code then how the page autosubmit...it not take any action

Comment: Sir if i run this code then i have no need to add setTimeout(function () { document.forms["form1"].submit(); }, 8000); .....If i am not add this then not autosubmit....and if i use your code then its not move to another page